# what does "with four no. 10 tins of Seven X per carton" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading this article, and found one sentence that I couldn't understand.
https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-for-Coca-Cola-to-not-reveal-what-is-in-the-recipe/answer/Donald-Pearline

What does this mean? 
"At the plant level we received cartons with four no. 10 tins of Seven X per carton, unlabeled except as Seven X." mean

Answer (score 2):

"Seven X" is the name of the ingredient put on the cans by Coca-Cola to keep its true identity secret.

"No 10" is a size of can. I'm not familiar with American can sizes, but I'd guess that it was reasonably large.

"unlabeled except as Seven X" means that the only label on the can was "Seven X", there were no other identifying marks.

So the whole sentence means

> We received cartons each containing 4 off size 10 cans of an ingredient known only as "Seven X"